# How to tell a search engine to only search in secure sites for results

Tags: search, https

Is there a way using google or bing or any other well known search engine to restrict searches to only https sites?

Comment: Yes. You can have your own code filter the results.

Comment: Can you please help me develope one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a regular browser, you can Google for the following:

```
inurl:https hello
```